# How do I change window managers with Yocto Project tools?

Tags: x11, yocto, window-managers, bitbake, metacity

#### My Intent

I have an image generated by BitBake on which I'm interested in changing the window manager to metacity or maybe something similar.

#### My Process

I've added `require recipes-graphics/images/core-image-x11.bb` into my core recipe, which provides a simple Matchbox terminal window but seemingly no other functionality. If I add `matchbox-desktop` and `matchbox-session-sato`, it adds a bit more usability but not what I'm looking for.

I've included the default package from the `metacity_2.34.13.bb` recipe from the `meta-gnome` layer from the [OpenEmbedded Metadata Index](http://layers.openembedded.org/layerindex/branch/master/layers/) in the `IMAGE_INSTALL` variable of my core image. This installs several components including a `metacity` command in `/usr/bin`. If I run that command, I get the following message:

```
GLib-GIO-Message: Using the 'memory' GSettings backend. Your settings will not be saved or shared with other applications

(metacity:1124): GLib-GIO-ERROR **: Settings schema 'org.gnome.metacity' is not installed

Trace/breakpoint trap
```

I've navigated to `/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas` and run `glib-compile-schemas .`, then run:

```
startx
metacity --replace
```

again. Now, the output is:

```
Window manager error: Unable to open X display
```

I haven't found a clear solution to this error which applies to my specific situation.

#### *Update (2/29):*

I may have now found a solution to this error, using these commands:

```
X&
export DISPLAY=:0
metacity&
```

At this point, I seem to be running something on one of my VTs. I can run demos like `glxgears` in that VT (`glxgears` is included in the `mesa-demos` recipe), but I don't know how to actually create a usable environment.

#### My question<s>(s)</s>

1. I'm not using much from `meta-openembedded/meta-gnome` (just `metacity`) or `meta/recipes-gnome` (`adwaita-icon-theme`, `gnome-desktop3`, `gsettings-desktop-schemas` and `gtk+3`), so am I missing some recipe which automates the addition of metacity?
2. <s>(if not Question 1) How can I solve the error `Window manager error: Unable to open X display`?</s>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `x11-common` recipe adds a X session script that will run `/usr/bin/x-session-manager`: that is responsible for starting your desktop environment.

The way to implement a new session/DE in OE-Core is to use [update-alternatives](http://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/current/ref-manual/ref-manual.html#ref-classes-update-alternatives) for "x-session-manager": see the matchbox-session recipe for the default implementation and mini-x-session recipe for an alternative.

mini-x-session might be modifiable for your needs so you don't need to write a new one: A `/etc/mini_x/session` file like this might do the trick:

```
# start any apps here, e.g. "my-desktop &"
exec metacity
```

Going from this (a running window manager) to "usable environment" might still be lots and lots of work, depending on your definition of usable.